# Cast a DataGridViewRow to a CustomDataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable

Currently, I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable.

```
dataGridView.SetDataSource(datatable);
```

The datatable is populated from an adapter.

```
adapter.Fill(datatable);
```

I need to add additional rows to the DataGridView that comes from another Query. The columns are identical.
I need to differ between the rows that comes from the current datatable and the second datatable. For that, I will add a new field to each one of the 2 queries for identication.
I though creating a new class CustomDataGridViewRow which derived from DataGridViewRow and change one of its appearance properties (color, font, style, etc...) in order to allow the user to differentiate between them.

```
public class CustomDataGridViewRow : DataGridViewRow
{
      // set some appearance properties in order to the user to differ between the 2 type of rows
}
```

Since currently, the DataGridView is bound to the DataTable and I prefer not to change this behavior. I though subscribing to RowAdded event and according to the identification column information,  to cast the DataGridViewRow to CustomDataGridViewRow. 
I tried the following but I am not sure how to make it work.

```
private void dataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex] as CustomDataGridViewRow;            
    }
```

Is there a way to cast the DataGridViewRow to CustomDataGridViewRow?

Update:
I observed that RowsAdded event is not firing since I am not adding the rows using Rows.Add method. SO this is another problem. After finding a way to cast the DataGridViewRow to CustomDataGridViewRow, I need to found a place where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialiaze your `DataGridView`, you have to specify a `RowTemplate` :

```
dataGridView1.RowTemplate = new CustomDataGridViewRow();
```

Then, when rows are added, `CustomDataGridViewRow` are automatically created, and you do not have to handle the `RowsAdded` event.

Comment: But I need to have a mix of two kind of DataGridViewRow. The default one and the CustomDataGridViewRow.

Comment: Couldn't you do that in your `CustomDataGridViewRow` class ? Declare a flag in this class that will determine whether default `DataGridViewRow` behaviors will be overridden for the row.